# JOIN - why these queries provide different output?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, inner-join

I have used a sample database to test out two queries. I expected them to have the same output, but the output is different and I can't understand why.

Could anyone please explain to me:

1. Why ver 3 provides different output than ver 2 ?
2. What is it about rows 10 24 33 41 50 59 67 73 100 132 139 147 162 169 that caused them to be excluded from ver 3 output ? I can't find any differentiating factor from all other rows that were included in the output.

Ver 2 code

```
SELECT 
    de.emp_no, de.from_date, de.to_date
FROM
    dept_emp_dup de
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, to_date
    FROM
        dept_emp_dup
    WHERE
        to_date > SYSDATE()
    GROUP BY emp_no) de1 ON de1.emp_no = de.emp_no
WHERE
    de1.to_date = de.to_date;
```

Ver 3 code

```
SELECT 
    de.emp_no, de.from_date, de.to_date
FROM
    dept_emp_dup de
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, to_date
    FROM
        dept_emp_dup
    GROUP BY emp_no) de1 ON de1.emp_no = de.emp_no
WHERE
    de1.to_date > SYSDATE()
        AND de1.to_date = de.to_date;
```

The excel file in this [LINK](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Bp1tcy4c#link) below contains sheets with

1. the full data
2. the correct output as filtered in excel
3. ver 2 query output
4. ver 3 query output

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this is extremely likely a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in the first query is not well formed, and unfortunately MySQL accepts it and runs it. This is the code you have:

```
SELECT 
  emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, to_date
FROM
  dept_emp_dup
WHERE
  to_date > SYSDATE()
GROUP BY emp_no
```

All columns not included in the GROUP BY clause should be aggregated in the select list. The *offending column* is `to_date`. In short, it should me modified either to:

```
SELECT emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, to_date
FROM dept_emp_dup
WHERE to_date > SYSDATE()
GROUP BY emp_no, to_date -- added to the GROUP BY clause
```

or to:

```
SELECT emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, 
  MAX(to_date) as to_date -- aggregated with MAX()
FROM dept_emp_dup
WHERE to_date > SYSDATE()
GROUP BY emp_no
```